# Modal controller not getting resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, typescript

I'm trying to open a modal window using angular/angular-ui-bootstrap which works perfectly for the view, however the corresponding controller doesn't seem to get resolved and angular doesn't spit out any errors. What could be wrong here?

```
// calling controller
export class TestController {

    private _modal : angular.ui.bootstrap.IModalService;

    constructor($modal : angular.ui.bootstrap.IModalService) {
        this._modal = $modal;
    }

    edit(myEntity : IEntity) {

        this._modal.open({
            templateUrl: "app/modules/stuff/entity.detail.modal.html",
            controller: "App.Stuff.EntityDetailModalController as modal",
            resolve: {
                item: () => myEntity
            }
        });

    }

}

// modal controller
export class EntityDetailModalController {
    constructor($modalInstance: angular.ui.bootstrap.IModalServiceInstance, item) {
        // ...
    }
}

// controller registration
stuffModule.controller("App.Stuff.EntityDetailModalController", ["$modalInstance", "item", EntityDetailModalController]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller name should be specified without "AS", you may specify controller alias separately:

```
this._modal.open({
            templateUrl: "app/modules/stuff/entity.detail.modal.html",
            controller: "App.Stuff.EntityDetailModalController",
            controllerAs: "modal",
            resolve: {
                item: () => myEntity
            }
        });
```